# cannot adjust brightness in ubuntu gnome

Tags: 14.04, intel-graphics, brightness, asus

I just installed ubuntu 14.04 gnome edition. I cant change my brightness using my keyboard shortcuts. I tried to install a gnome shell extension, but its not  compatible with ubuntu 14.04. I cant find a way to turn on my keyboard backlight also. Please help. Please note that i am new to gnome, i have been using unity for 3 years
Laptop model : Asus UX303 LN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For new ASUS laptops and this model in particular you will need to edit `/etc/default/grub` file and add a xorg config.

1. Run in terminal

   ```
   sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
   ```

   and edit this line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to look like this

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="
   ```
2. Run in terminal

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
3. Run in terminal

   ```
   sudo -H gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
   ```

   and paste to the editor this text

   ```
   Section "Device"
        Identifier "card0"
        Driver "intel"
        Option "Backlight" "intel_backlight"
        BusID "PCI:0:2:0"
   EndSection
   ```
4. Save file and reboot.

This will enable Fn buttons to control screen backlight.

Regarding keyboard backlight I suggest asking a separate question.

Comment: thank you very much man! that worked!!! i will post another question for keyboard backlight

Comment: What if I have another monitor? Only the main monitor got controlled, the other one did not.

Comment: THIS WORKS `xrandr --output VGA1 --brightness 0.8`